# Add layouts to a fragment programmaticcaly

Tags: java, android, layout, android-fragments

**Introduction**
I want to have different fragments depending on the user's choice from the navigation drawer. For every item in the navigation drawer is a different site that should called. I want to achieve this by fragments. 
The main fragment will get displayed first by doing the following in the onCreate-method

```
if ( savedInstanceState == null ) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = MainFragment.passList(hashMap);
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainFragment());
    ft.commit();
}
```

As you can see I'm passing data (a hashmap) to a method of the fragment which works perfectly. The data then gets put into string arrays. This works and the data can also be used in the onCreate-method of the fragment.

This is the xml of the main activity

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
       android:layout_width="240dp"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="start"
       android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
       android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
       android:dividerHeight="0.1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this is the XML of the main fragment

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainRelativeLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:paddingRight="10dp"
   >
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.03" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainListView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

What I want to achieve now is to display data in the scroll view. But the question I have, is how do I populate that and how do I initliaze it?

Normally I would go and just create them like that - because findViewById doesn't work in a Fragment (Have to write the method by my own)

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(getActivity());
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout ( getActivity() );

sv.addView(ll); 
ll.addView(SAMPLETEXTVIEW);

View mainView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    return mainView;
```

but that just leaves me with a blank screen and no actual text added. How can I achieve this? The data is there - I know that, because it gets printed out with System.out.println - I just need a way to display it. Thx in advance!

**EDIT**

When I do it like that

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);

    ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainScrollView);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

    sv.addView(ll);
```

I get just an IllegalStateException that ScrollView can only host one direct child... But I don't get it. The linearlayout is the only thing that is the direct child. Why is there a problem?

Here is the complete `onCreateView`-method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);

    ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainScrollView);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mainListView);

    sv.addView(ll); 
    source      = new TextView[hashMapSize];


    for (int i = 0; i < hashMapSize; i++) {

        source[i]       = new TextView(getActivity());
source      [i].setText( "Source: "     + sourceArr     [i] );
ll.addView(source[i]

    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the `IllegalStateException` is because you inflate your R.layout.main_fragment which already contains your ScrollView that already has *one direct child* (declared in you layout xml).

You shouldn't add in code with `sv.addView(ll)` it's already there. All you need to do is get the references as you already do with `findViewById`.

Remove the `sv.addView(ll);` and you should be fine.

Comment: sometimes a fresh pair of eyes is all it takes :)